# UMP ConsentStatus always "NotRequired" when testing

Tags: admob

I have incorporated Google's UserMessagingPlatform into my Android project for user consent to be compliant with GDPR for AdMob.

The problem is that the ConsentStatus always returns "NotRequired" when I test it on my phone. I have tried testing using Geography = DebugGeography.Eea but this does not make any difference. Furthermore, since I am based in EEA/UK this should not be required.

I am also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app and using Reset() but this does not work either.

Form Status is always "Available" and when I force the form to show without checking ConsentStatus it works fine (I have checked and it has registered in the AdMob interface as a message shown).

I am using the Xamarin cross-platform bindings for UMP (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform/1.0.0).

The Google documentation https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start only mentions the following as an example for why consent would give not required as a response:

ConsentStatus.NOT_REQUIRED: User consent not required. For example, the user is not in the EEA or the UK.

Comment: Any chance you're also setting [tagForUnderAgeOfConsent](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting#users_under_the_age_of_consent)? A child user would not be able to consent, so that's another possible reason you'd get NotRequired, even in the EEA.

Comment: Nope not using that tag and it doesn't apply to me

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is due to a different order of required cases in Android and iOS modules:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface ConsentStatus {
        int UNKNOWN = 0;
        int NOT_REQUIRED = 1;
        int REQUIRED = 2;
        int OBTAINED = 3;
    }

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UMPConsentStatus) {
  UMPConsentStatusUnknown = 0,      ///< Unknown consent status.
  UMPConsentStatusRequired = 1,     ///< User consent required but not yet obtained.
  UMPConsentStatusNotRequired = 2,  ///< Consent not required.
  UMPConsentStatusObtained =
  3,  ///< User consent obtained, personalized vs non-personalized undefined.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with the same problem. The reason NOT_REQUIRED is always returned is that the test device ID has not been registered. DebugGeography does not apply to non-test devices. In my case, even if it is a basic Android emulator, I had to register the test device ID to resolve this issue. Your emulator's device ID is displayed in logcat as follows when ConsentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate is called.

`Use new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder().addTestDeviceHashedId("xxxxxxxxx") to set this as a debug device.`

**EDIT:** I did more tests. It requires a test device ID since Android API 30. Until API 29, it is not necessary to specify the test device ID. I'm not sure if this is only for my development environment.

Comment: Android emulators used to be whitelisted by default. Looks like it has changed now. Adding hashed device ID fixed the issue.